# What the difference between ng-content to @Input?

Tags: html, angular

What the difference between ng-content to @Input?

If I have a component `<app-parent> </app-parent>` I can pass data in two ways.

with ng-content & @Input
What the difference between both of them?
And which situation I choose each of them?

For example

```
// First way
- Child ts
@Input() data

- Html child
<h1>{{data}}</h1>
---------------------------------
// Second way
- Parent html
<h1>data</h1>

- Child html
<ng-content><ng-content>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `ng-content` is content projection not for sharing data like `@Input` between parent and child.

Comment: But how can I choose each of them? projection and transfer data bring me the data as same as I need it